# Adding a contact to mac contacts?

Tags: java, c, macos, contacts

Is there a library that would let me somehow add a contact to mac contacts? I prefer java or C, but another language would be okay too.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean this:http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AddingProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001026-BABHHIHC?

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to add contacts, or anything else to do with the OS X Address Book, is to use one of Apple's documented APIs.  The easiest to use is the [Apple Events scripting interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptx/Concepts/work_with_as.html), either through AppleScript or an equivalent like [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) from Python, Ruby, or Objective C.  See [here](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.10/ScriptingAddressBook/index.html) for an AppleScript example.

At a lower level, using Objective C, you can directly use the Address Book framework.  See the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/AddressBook.html) for more info.  There are also high-level bridges to the framework, like in [PyObjC](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/documentation/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/api-notes-AddressBook.html).